# C++ Placement new and initializatoin

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm doing some cheesy tick where I initialize parts of a class object in a placement new, and then leave those parts blank in the constructor. I figure it might be undefined behavior but I'm not sure.  I see in the standard it says "no initialization is performed." for built in types so now I'm thinking it might actually be legal.  It does in fact work, at least in MS Visual Studio.  I just wanted to see if it's actually undefined behavior, defined, or it's a gray area.

Edit: This isn't the actual code (because that's a bit complicated) but it's kind of what I'm doing, although there are more fields that get passed through. This runs as expected.

```
#include <iostream>

class CPlacementNew
{

public:

   CPlacementNew(double fDbl) : 
      m_fRestOfData(fDbl) {}

   void *operator new(size_t size, unsigned int iExtra)
   {
      CPlacementNew *ptr = (CPlacementNew *) malloc(size+iExtra);
      ptr->m_iSize = (int) size+iExtra;
      return (void *) ptr;
   }

   void operator delete(void *ptr)
   {
      free(ptr);
   }

   void PrintSize()
   {
       std::cout << "Size = " << m_iSize << std::endl;
   }

private:

   int m_iSize;
   double m_fRestOfData;

};


class CPlacementNewChild: public CPlacementNew
{
public:
   CPlacementNewChild(double fDbl1, double fDbl2) : 
      CPlacementNew(fDbl1), m_fMoreData(fDbl2) {}

private:

   double m_fMoreData;

};

int main()
{
    CPlacementNew      *pPW1 = new(16) CPlacementNew(1.0);
    CPlacementNewChild *pPWC = new(16) CPlacementNewChild(1.0,2.0);
    pPW1->PrintSize();
    pPWC->PrintSize();
    delete pPW1;
    delete pPWC;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you are asking about.

Comment: my crystal ball says it is likely undefined behavior. But for a definitive answer it asks for a premium subscription and I am not falling for that ... again

Comment: Sounds like a great way to experience *undefined behavior* up close and personal.  But maybe you have a very good reason to not have the overhead of initialization, because you've profiled your code.

Comment: It has nothing to do with speed.  In new you get passed the size of the object and that's always correct even if you subclass it.  So it's pretty convenient if you need that information. This is for a specialized heap implementation.

Answer (score 3):

C++20 established rules for creating objects via `malloc` which are reasonable to apply regardless of language version.  Those rules do not apply to `CPlacementNew` because its constructor is non-trivial, but even
if they did, creating that containing object **reuses** the storage of the contained `int`, giving it an indeterminate value ([basic.indet]/1); it is relative to *that* state that “no initialization is performed”, so it is undefined behavior to use `m_iSize`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. The question doesn't really have to do with malloc. I'm just using it here as an example. In the real code I use system routines. The question boils down to, does C++ guarantee that memory is unchanged between leaving placement new and the constructor. The standard uses the word uninitialized, so it might.

Comment: @Gnollrunner: Previous versions of the standard didn’t even say that you could get objects at all from such routines, so *any* assignment via a cast like yours to `ptr->m_iSize` was already undefined behavior.  My point is that even if that were allowed, which it still isn’t for this type, the value is not usable later.